# How to append a string into a list without its new line "\n" in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.5

I have a text file something like this (suppose A and B are persons and below text is a conversation between them):

```
A: Hello
B: Hello
A: How are you?
B: I am good. Thanks and you?
```

I added this conversation into a list that returns below result:

```
[['A', 'Hello\n'], ['A', 'How are you?\n'], ['B', 'Hello\n'], ['B', 'I am good. Thanks and you?\n']]
```

I use these commands in a loop:

```
new_sentence = line.split(': ', 1)[1]
attendees_and_sentences[index].append(person)
attendees_and_sentences[index].append(new_sentence)

print(attendees_and_sentences) # with this command I get the above result
print(attendees_and_sentences[0][1]) # if I run this one, then I don't get "\n" in the sentence.
```

The problem is those "\n" characters on my result screen. How can I get rid of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Python's [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) function.

For example:

```
>>> 'my string\n'.rstrip()
'my string'
```

And if you want to trim the trailing newlines while preserving other whitespace, you can specify the characters to remove, like so:

```
>>> 'my string  \n'.rstrip()
'my string  '
```